# How do I uninstall Java?

Tags: macos, java

I have several Java installations on my machine:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (6):
    1.6.0_24-b07-334, x86_64: "Java SE 6"   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_24-b07-334.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_24-b07-334, i386:   "Java SE 6"   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_24-b07-334.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_24-b07-334, x86_64: "Java SE 6"   /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_24-b07-334, i386:   "Java SE 6"   /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_22-b04-307, x86_64: "Java SE 6"   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_22-b04-307.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_22-b04-307, i386:   "Java SE 6"   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_22-b04-307.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I don't need them all. For example I don't need update 22 version. How can I uninstall it cleanly?

I would also like to get rid of those 'duplicate' JVMs, but I need to have sources around, since I do lot of Java developement, so that may not be possible. Why are there so many of them anyway?

Comment: `rm -rf /path/` ?

Comment: bckbck: Won't that break anything? I thought that those JVMs are registered somewhere.

Comment: random guess...

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work. Hopefully I didn't break anything :)

Comment: :O, you actually did that?

Comment: Lol ... yes. I did some reading to learn difference between JVMs in /System and /Library and I went ahead and removed JVMs in /Library, since those are developer JVMs. Then I have installed latest Java Developer Pack instead (I've also updated JVM in /System through standard Software Update). Java_home tool now shows only existing JVMs and Java Preferences panel also shows only real JVMs, so I guess I'm fine.

Comment: Similar: [Uninstalling Java on Lion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/24131/8546)

Answer (score 2):

After some reading:

JVM in /System is system-wide installation of Java, which is always installed on Snow Leopard, and is updated through standard Software Update mechanism.  I don't think it would be good idea to remove this JVM, but haven't tried it ... maybe nothing bad will happen (if you don't use Java).

My JVMs in /Library are from Java Developer Package, which also contain sources and documentation. It **seems** that it is OK to simply remove them. After I have removed them, `java_tool` is no longer showing them.

(After this, I've updated my Java to latest one available from Apple, and also installed latest Java Developer Package, which added new JVM into /Library again. Since I use Java sources and documentation in my IDE, I will let it live).

Answer (score 0):

Right now the System and the available Developer Java version is a the same version level, so the Developer version doesn't give you any benefits - for the moment.

The Developer version is used when distribution Applications with an embedded JDK, and when doing experimental development with new Java releases - and hereby the System wide version won't be touched.

Comment: Developer version has Java sources and Javadocs. Java sources are often used by IDEs for showing parameter names or documentation.