# Lion (10.7.2) -- CPU heats to 90-degrees and Java apps crash -- why?

Tags: macos, crash, temperature, macbook-pro

MacBook Pro 15" quad-i7.  Been running Lion since day one.

Just started this week, Eclipse and Oracle SQL Developer crash unexpectedly, then a moment later the MacBook cooling fans kick in and the machine is hot to the touch.

I installed iStat Pro and it looks like the CPU temperature approached 90-degrees at the time of the crash.

Any ideas why this would suddenly start happening?

Rob

Comment: It's what you get for using Eclipse :D.

Comment: Is 90° really that high? My processor gets above that just when I'm not doing anything, and the fans don't really start to kick in until at least 120°. (15" MacBook Pro 2010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Lion. This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For the CPU temperature to get those sorts of levels something needs to be hammering the processor pretty hard. I'd start by looking at Activity Monitor to spot which particular process has decided it wants a supercomputer cooling system.

If it turns out to be Java (which is likely), trash Java from your system and then reinstall it from there. It could be a damaged cache file, the application might have corrupt preferences, or some other combination.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you happen to know how I would delete Java from my Mac, and reinstall it?  Pretty sure the Software Update put my current Java in place.

Comment: This site to the rescue [an Apple SE post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24131/uninstalling-java-on-lion).