# Can't update Java due to apparently newer version already installed

Tags: macos, java

I'm trying to update Java on my MacBook (OS X 10.9.5). When I download the most resent version (v8 update 40) from java.com and try to install it, it pops up an error box saying

> You are trying to install 1.8.40.27, however 14.9.0 is already installed

and that's it. In a terminal I get

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

But Firefox → Tools → Add-ons shows Java 14.9.0 (and says it's outdated), though there is no option to de-install it.

So, how can I install the most recent Java 8.40? How can I uninstall this mysterious Java 14.9.0?

Comment: The java command line does not show the version used in the browser - do you just want to update the browser? Where exactly in Firefox Add ons dopes it show Java - In plugins I have Java Applet Plug-in  Java 8 Update 49

Comment: thanks Mark. I have sorted this now using klanomath's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [apple.discussions.com](https://discussions.apple.com/message/27768834#27768834) the install of Java8 should work after removing an older Java plugin with the following command:

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
```

Comment: That did it for me (somehow that discussion didn't show up on my searches). However, `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin` was only a link to another location, so the `rm` only removed the link, but not the directory linked to. Shouldn't I remove that to?

Comment: @Walter Where does (or better did) the alias link to?

Comment: to  `/System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`

Comment: @Walter This is the old (1.6) plugin from Apple. After installing Java 8 you will have a new one at "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/". You may just leave the old one where it is.

Comment: Why should I keep it there? Is it ever needed again? Why '(1.6)'? What about the whole directory at `/System/Library/Java`? Is this still needed?

Comment: @Walter You may completely [uninstall](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74243/uninstall-java-mountain-lion) Java6 (also check the [linked](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24131/uninstalling-java-on-lion) question there) and install [JDK8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) instead. You will get a proper `java -version`  output then.

Comment: I'm not using java directly, so won't need JDK8, but you didn't answer my questions from the previous comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22162/discussion-between-klanomath-and-walter).

Comment: If you feel uncomfortable using sudo, you can open the directory in Finder instead: `open '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/'`  then you just drag the plugin to Trash.